# Shell driver install with `ACCEPT_EULA=Y` error

Tags: bash, environment-variables, installation, driver, eula

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), I am trying to install the following driver in shell, using this code (modified from the original slightly):

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

But I get an error on the last command:

```
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: ACCEPT_EULA
```

After searching, I can't seem to find this exact error anywhere else.

One solution is to run the last command without `ACCEPT_EULA=Y` as `sudo apt-get install msodbcsql17`. And then to enter `Y` at the prompt. This indeed works but I would like to run the above installation for other users without need of their input.

- Is there a way to resolve the above error so I can use `ACCEPT_EULA=Y`, or
- alternatively is there a simple way to enter the `Y` response for the EULA
  automatically so the end user never needs to take any action?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a configuration setting of `sudo`.

Comment: You need to modify `/etc/sudoers` to allow it.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to have access to run arbitrary commands, but not to modify the environment.

The simple workaround is to hand off environment changes to the command:

```
sudo env ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!
In case this additional context helps anyone else: The situation you described about access to run commands but not to modify the environment, might be explained by the fact that this is a spun up Linux environment that is provided as a service by an external company. (not sure if that matters)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment.
But I was doing the same install for pyodbc inside a python:3 docker container.
In the dockerfile the following command works:

ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

(I was after this particular driver #17.)

Reading: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/oss-drivers/pyodbc/Dockerfile can help see the environment set up from a base ubuntu (ubuntu:16.04) box.

Also check up on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
for microsoft first hand docs.

Answer (score 1):

The `ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17` command above did the trick for me as I was trying to set up `msodbcsql17` via a `Dockerfile`.